# Is "After elapsing some time" correct?

Tags: synonyms

I wanna say "Aafter some time since the beginning of the event participants were quite bored".
Can I say "After elapsing some time in the event participants were quite bored"?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elapse means 'pass' or 'slip by' (http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/elapse) so it's time that passes. Your construction implies that first your participants slipped some time and then got bored. If you insist on using 'elapse' this is better:

At the event the participants were quite bored after some time elapsed.

But I would use:

After a while the participants grew bored at the event.